# dplyr: error selecting columns in a data_frame with duplicate names

Tags: r, dplyr

Since `data_frame` does not check variable names, it is possible to define a `data_frame` with duplicate column names. But, when trying to select columns based on column names, `dplyr` complains that there are duplicate names even when there is no ambiguity about the selection.

For example, in the selection below, even though there are two columns with the name `var3`, given the desired selection, **both** would need to be dropped, so it is not clear why `dplyr` complains, and whether it should.

```
df_x = data_frame(var1 = rnorm(100), 
           var2 = rnorm(100),
           var3 = rnorm(100), 
           var3 = rnorm(100))

df_x %>% 
  select(var1:var2)
```

Comment: It is not recommended to have duplicate column names

Comment: @akrun I probably have a good use case for using duplicate names.

Comment: In `matrix` it can be used, but most of the operations in `dplyr` and other packages don't recommend this due to obvious reasons.  You can use `make.unique(names(df_x))` to change it to unique column names, and then use `select` with `matches`

Comment: You can try `df_x %>% setNames(., make.unique(names(.))) %>% select(var1:var2)`  Note that in this case, the original column names in `df_x` is not changed and you can do whatever operations with the `select`ed columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would to be change the column names with `make.unique` and then `select`

```
 df_x %>% 
     setNames(., make.unique(names(.))) %>% 
     select(var1:var2)
```

If we need to select the `var3` columns

```
df_x %>%
     setNames(., make.unique(names(.)))  %>%
     select(matches("^var3")) %>%
     head(2)  
#       var3     var3.1
#       (dbl)      (dbl)
#1  1.2590590  0.9784617
#2 -0.7163919 -0.9644718
```